# Why am I getting null when trying to retrieve a value from a ContentValues object?

Tags: android

I am getting a NullPointerException when trying to retrieve/insert values from a ContentValues object that I'm a passing to my database method. I have several columns in my db table and instead of passing all those as params to the method, I'm trying to simplify it a little bit.

Here's a sample of the code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
 private Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

  // other methods in here....

 public void onClick( View v ) {
    int year = calendar.get( Calendar.YEAR );
    int month = calendar.get( Calendar.MONTH );
    int date = calendar.get( Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK );
    int weekOfYear = calendar.get( Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR );

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put( YEAR, year );
    values.put( MONTH, month );
    values.put( DATE, date );
    values.put( WEEK_OF_YEAR, weekOfYear );

    if( everythingIsGood ) {
      // the problem starts after this.
      mDb.addToDatabase( values );

    }
 }
```

Here's the database method:

```
public class Database {
  // other methods....

  public long addToDatabase( ContentValues values ) {
    // I'm getting a NullPointerException right here, trying to retrieve 
    // a value from this ContentValues object 
    int weekOfYear = values.getAsInteger( WEEK_OF_YEAR );
    values.remove( WEEK_OF_YEAR );

    // do other stuff

    long pId = this.getParentId( weekOfYear );

   // And, if I take the above out, right here
   values.put( PARENT_ID, pId );

  mDb.insert( table_name, null, values );
  }
}
```

So, am I not allowed to manipulate the ContentValues object? Is this bad practice, should I just pass all those variables to the method?

Note: I know for a fact that the values are not null.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you get a `NullPointerException` on this line it means that your `values` object is null. What you posted is the full `onClick` method?

Comment: What I posted was a summary. I don't know what I was doing wrong before but its working now. I've been trying to figure it out for hours. How can access a member variable of `MyActivity` class inside the `onClick` method

Comment: The last part of your comment is a question? You can access any members of you `MyActivity` in the `onClick` by simple referencing them.

Comment: Yeah, that was a stupid question. I knew that. I need to get some sleep

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like you opened the database mDb, bro.  You gotta do that.

Comment: I summarized the code. the `// other methods...` part did all that. The problem was manipulating the ContentValues object.